# Why should I use batch_length divided by num_steps to determine the epoch_size?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on the RNN tutorial with PTB dataset(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/reader.py). In this tutorial, they simply divide the (number of batches) by the (number of steps(or look_back)) to determine the epoch size.

```
    epoch_size = (batch_len - 1) // num_steps
```

or

```
    epoch_size = ((len(data) // batch_size) - 1) // num_steps
```

In my thought, it would be better to use `(number of batches) - (number of steps) + 1` for epoch size. There would be more data to train and I think its more reasonable since the model can learn all sequences of the data.

Comment: Do you mean to ask if it's better to use longer largely intersecting yet technically different sets of batches rather than smaller independent ones? If so then no, if many epochs contain same certain batches then RNN will overtrain and will always output same sequence if it encounters first word of it.

Comment: @IcedLance You say its all about the overfitting? Thanks! It really helps me. Hope you have a nice day.